# How can I send regularly scheduled emails without setting up a cron job?

Tags: php, email, smtp, cron, scheduled-tasks

I'm setting up a subscription site using PHP that will allow admins to set up schedules (monthly, weekly, daily, all down to the minute) for when emails will be sent out to subscribers. Is there a plugin, extension, or even a library, that allows me to send these emails based on a predetermined schedule?

I thought of setting a cron script to check every minute for pending emails, but with amount of traffic I'm estimating for my site I'm worried that it would put too much of a strain on my servers.

It would also be nice if this plugin, extension, etc, could provide analytic data in return. But that's definitely not vital.

Comment: How would an alternative reduce the load on your server? Or are you looking for a 3rd part email-sending service? - PHP doesn't run in the background. The only way to do what you said is to check for new things to do every time someone visits your site. Cron is best.

Comment: I think this is exactly what cron is for.

Comment: Ideally I'd like a 3rd party to handle the actual processing. It's not so much the cron I'm worried about, but the script it will be executing. So if I can outsource that part, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

The cronjob service itself takes little resources. It is the work that is done by the scripts it calls that have any impact whatsoever on your server. This means that whatever approach you use to send emails regularly, cronjob, or something else, the load the server takes by sending those mails will be the same. So if your server is slowing down too much, you probably need a dedicated server or more resources. The cron services itself does slow anything down (unless you are calling it like 10 times a second)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not actually that concerned about the cronjob itself causing a lag. The script itself may be processing A LOT of information and I'd prefer to outsource at least some of that work to a 3rd party extension.

Answer (score 0):

You could call php script from outside, from somewhere where you will be able to setup scheduled calls (may be your PC or other hosting service). Most shared hostings supporting schedules. Look into control panel (cpanel, plesk, ...):